# firebug returns syntax error in doctype?

Tags: html, firebug

Why does Firebug return an error in my doctype?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

## error

```
syntax error
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
```

## source code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
.....
```

Comment: Is this the very first line in your HTML page?

Comment: There's no real reason not to use `<!doctype html>` instead of the long version.

Comment: yes.. its the first line

Comment: @Zanfa — Wanting to use a mature validator for a mature specification instead of an experimental validator for a draft, and changing, specification is a real reason.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This usually happens because you are loading an HTML document as a script. This is often caused by  `<script src=""></script>` (i.e. a relative URI pointing at the current, HTML, document)) or one of the scripts pointing to a 404 error.

Comment: just saved me a load of time. nice one

Comment: I was getting this error from a script tag trying to load a `.js` file that I had stopped using, and had deleted, but hadn't removed the `<script>` tag from my index file.

Comment: Great answer! Although, it's not necessary due to a 404 error but the resource not being available in general. In my case, I encountered this error and the response was 302 Found  but size of received js file was zero.

Answer (score 0):

DOCTYPE normally is expressed on one line like below. and can cause syntax error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

But even sometimes it will yell about a syntax error when a src attribute is not declared for an element. Firebug can also through this error when a source is not found or is called twice on one page. EX: script/image/link.

Comment: White space is allowed in the middle of the Doctype, and [even appears in the example usage in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/loosedtd.html)

Comment: Where not talking about specification but an add-on that throughs an error. I have had firebug through a syntax error for having the doctype with white spaces.