# syntax error for xhtml doctype in header

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c, doctype, dtd

Firebug is reporting a syntax error for the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1- transitional.dtd">
```

I don't understand why since it has worked fine for the past 2 months!

Comment: possible duplicate of [firebug returns syntax error in doctype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714896/firebug-returns-syntax-error-in-doctype)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to load an HTML document as JavaScript, either because you are sourcing a 404 document or because you've forgotten to add the URI and thus created a relative URI back to the current document (`<script src=""></script>`).

When interpreted as JS, the Doctype is a syntax error.