# JSONP and DOCTYPE Errors

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, xml-rpc, doctype

I'm running into a  weird problem.

I'm communicating with my server using AJAX. (I'm running my web application on `localhost`).
Server is located on, say, `http://www.example.com`

To bypass the Same Origin Policy, I'm using JSONP. I dynamically create a `<script>` tag and load the data from my server.

So far so good.

Then I decided to upload my web application to this subdomain: `http://m.example.com`

That's when I run into crazy errors. Sometimes the page loads, sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't load, Firebug throws a `DOCTYPE` error.

I did some research and came across this stackoverflow post: [firebug returns syntax error in doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714896/firebug-returns-syntax-error-in-doctype)

**Quoting an answer in this link:**

> This usually happens because you are loading an HTML document as a script. This is often caused by `<script src=""></script>` (i.e. a relative URI pointing at the current, HTML, document)) or one of the scripts pointing to a 404 error.

Pretty helpful stuff. Based on all that, I've concluded from all the above that whenever my server responds slowly, the `<script>` tag's `src` attribute is null. Since that throws a `404 error`, I get a `DOCTYPE` error in Firebug. Whenever my server responds quickly, there are no issues and everything works fine.

How do I solve this problem? I could put a manual timeout or something, but that wouldn't exactly be foolproof and an elegant solution.

Any help guys?

## EDIT:

**Here's some code:**

This function is used to create the `script` tag dynamically:

```
function appendScriptToHead() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");  
    element.src = 'http://www.example.com/?data&callback=callfunction'; 
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element) 
}
```

This callback function is called when the above url containing JSONP data is loaded:

```
function callfunction(response) {  
    alert(response);  
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some code of some sort.

Comment: Solve what problem? If you want to solve the `src` being `null`, add a check for `null` before inserting the script tag. If you want to be able to "catch" the error, timeouts are the way to go.

Comment: Hi @RoToRa. I've edited my question and included the code that I'm currently using to retrieve the JSONP data from my server. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Matt! Thanks for your input. Could you give me a little code sample how to check if `src` is null?

Comment: Is your actual code also missing "http://" in the URL?

Comment: @RoToRa I tried with `http://` too. Same issue pops up

Comment: when is the appendScriptToHead() function being called?

Comment: @ftom2 I call that function on body load. `<body onLoad=appendScriptToHead()>`

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a bit of misunderstanding here. Your `script` element will *always* have its `src` property set, but its contents depends on your server's response. I doubt it'll be error 404 (as it refers to the element not found, which is hardly repetitive), but it can be of 500 flavors.

I suggest debugging your queries just as they are (i.e., opening `http://www.example.com/?data&callback=%callfunction%` with your browser or some scripted HTTP UserAgent, if you feel industrious), to see what might be wrong with the logic which selects the script to be loaded.

Comment: Hi @raina77wow. I understand what you mean. I tried opening `http://www.example.com/?data&callback=%callfunction%` in my browser directly. It returns a JSONP string alright. But the server response varies. Sometimes it opens immediately, sometimes it takes a while. How can I bypass this uncertainity in code?

Comment: I'd suggest using the approach described [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768768/loading-javascript-dynamically-and-how-to-check-if-the-script-exists). No need to define an extra variable, though: you can just check the function you intend to load.