# Implementing URL slugs in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, slug

I'm trying to implement URL slugs in my app (python-based). I want the slugged URL to be of the format `myhost/{post_id}/{post_title}`.

When I try to access the page using the above slugged URL format, I get an error and (in Chrome, the error says - unexpected token <). If I delete the `/<post_title>` from the URL, the page loads correctly. Specifically, I noticed that once I have a 'forward slash' after the `<post_id>`, I have issues. Everything works fine without that extra slash (extra directory)

My code is:

```py
class mainhandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if (self.request.path == '/test'):
            path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), 'test.htm')
            self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
            self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))
        else:                       
            path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), 'index.htm')            
            self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'                 
            self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

    application = webapp.WSGIApplication( [('/.*', mainhandler)],  debug=True)
```

Basically, I want to load the `index.htm` file and on that file, I have JavaScript which is supposed to extract the `post-id` from the URL and do some stuff with it.

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extensive discussion with RocketDonkey, I tried something which worked.

I changed my script file from

```
<script src="include/load.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script **src="/include/load.js"** type="text/javascript"></script>
```

RocketDonkey's explanation for the working solution:  when you use a front slash, you are saying 'take this URL path from root'. But without it, it is in terms of the current location

This explains why the original code worked when my url was simply localhost:8081/1234 but not in the second scenario where I have a second directory

**NB: The solution described here was used in conjunction with the original proposal from rocketDonkey**

Answer (score 1):

You will need to modify the URL path that you have in your `application`. If I'm understanding correctly, you'll want to do something like this:

```py
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
    [('/(.*)/(.*)', mainhandler),
     ('/.*', mainhandler)],
    debug=True)
```

And then define your `mainhandler` as:

```py
class mainhandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, post_id=None, post_title=None):
```

Although it doesn't seem like you are doing anything with them at the moment, once in your `mainhandler` you will have those variables available to you. The reason your first mapping wasn't working was because it wasn't set up to handle additional `/`'s and items in the URL.

And per our subsequent conversation, the cause of the `syntaxError` (which is a JavaScript-related error) is because of the missing `/` in front of `include/load.js`. Without that prefix, the path is relative to the current location. In the case of `localhost:8080/1234/a-test-case`, it becomes `/1234/a-test-case/include/load.js`, which doesn't map to anything specific in `app.yaml` and therefore falls through to the `.*` handler (and **not** the Javascript handler you have defined), which returns you to the main script and follows the hanlder paths there. The link to your `.js.` now returns your `index.html` instead of your `.js` file, which causes an error (similar to what can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714896/firebug-returns-syntax-error-in-doctype)).

Comment: I tried your suggestion and nothing changed (i.e. still getting the error). In firebug, the error is `SyntaxError: syntax error
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//E`

Comment: @N.P Hmm, what is the exact URL you are trying to access?

Comment: an example is localhost:8081/1234/a-simple-example

Comment: @N.P Does that error come up in the GAE logs or only in Chrome/Firefox? Also, does it work fine when you just do `localhost:8081/1234`? Seems like it could be a problem with the template file itself - as a test, what happens if you strip out the JavaScript from your template?

Comment: It works fine if I just do localhost:8081/1234 and the javascript works. Also works fine if i add query parameters to the url

Comment: Tried stripping out the javascript and no error is reported. So apparently, the second forward slash has some issues with the javascript

Comment: @N.P And they are both pointing to the same template ('index.html')?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22870/discussion-between-n-p-and-rocketdonkey)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using webapp2 which has support for extended routes and Python 2.7.

[WebApp2 Routing](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html)